# Accessing file system on jailbroken iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, jailbreak

Short Question:

Is there a way to call the root file system (similar to iFile) from a jailbroken ios application in order to upload files from the local device to a server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe no one answered since April. Possibly you've already found the solution, but anyway: yes, you can. Check out the `NSFileManager` class:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/

Depending on whether you have text or binary files, you'd then need to check out either `NSString` or `NSData`, respectively (more info available in Apple's Documentation).

Just make sure your app is not running from the `/var/mobile/Applications` directory, but rather `/var/stash/Applications`.

Comment: Thanks. Awarded Answer just for the effort :)